# Inspect.exe missing in Windows SDK for Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, winapi

The Windows SDK for Server 2008 does not include Inspect.exe.
Does anyone know where I might find a copy of Inspect.exe or AccExplorer32.exe?
I'm running the 64 bit version of Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Solution:

1. Download the [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework
   4 (ISO)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8442)
2. Unzip using [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or a similar archive tool
3. Navigate to **Setup\WinSDKTools**
4. Open **cab1.cab** (this is just like a .zip file, any archving tool
   should be able to open it)
5. Locate **WinSDK_Inspect_exe_x86**, extract it to a folder somewhere,
   add the **.exe** extension
6. All done!

I should mention that [Window Detective](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowdetective/) does the same thing as Inspect.exe, but does it better, so it's an excellent alternative.

Comment: I can't see any Automation properties in Windows Detective?

Comment: When downloading the ISO, 3 files are displayed. I grabbed GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso and it had the correct file.

Comment: Window Detective is the same thing as Spy++. Don't waste time downloading it.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely enough. Microsoft site shows this [should be a part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of Windows SDK. Maybe you should try [some other version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/search.aspx?q=windows%20sdk) of SDK?

Comment: I thought so too, but I installed it and it's nowhere to be found. I am unable to get other versions to install, probably because it detects that it's the wrong version for Server 2008.  It does occur to me however, that most installation packages like this can be opened and browsed with an archive tool such as 7Zip, so I will go try that...

Comment: That did it. I'll award you the bounty because you led me to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Anders Thanks, glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Download a web installer - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138
Select just "Windows development tools" and "Debugging tools for Windows" to save your disk space.

It will take about 200 Mb.

Continue and enjoy!

Comment: This doesn't work once .NET 4.5 is installed (at least on Win 7)