# How to install the Inspect tool on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-10

Is [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a part of the Windows 10 standalone SDK?

Is there any alternative application to "inspect" for windows 10?
I want to install "inspect" tool on my machine running windows 10 build 10586 (for testing purpose).
According to Inspect documentation on MSDN it is not described if it is a part of win 10 sdk also or only upto win 8.1.
Also is there any alternative tool for "Inspect" to debug on windows 10?

Comment: Please **NEVER** download from unofficial source; It is not recommended: https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool/blob/master/Inspect.exe

Answer (score 37):

Since 10.0.15063 the directory of the tools has changed. See the changelog:

> To improve the developer experience, tools and metadata will lay down in versioned folders.
>   This will allow developers to isolate the SDK and tools between
>   releases.

You have to put the version of the Windows SDK between `bin` and `x64` (or `x86` or `arm`)

For me `inspect` is in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64`

The folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64` (without the SDK version) exists, but does not contain the `inspect` tool.

Needed Components for "Inspect":

[image: Needed Components for "Inspect"]

Comment: I have just tried the steps suggested above on latest version of windows 10 (10.0.16299.0) and am not getting the inspect.exe.

I am guessing something has changed in the SDK setup. Is there a changelog somewhere i can check?

Comment: update: i was able to get to the previous versions and get inspect that way through the [archive ](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)

Comment: inspect.exe not working on my windows 11

Comment: inspect.exe is available on windows 11, I followed the instructions after downloading Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621.0) https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2237387
The correct path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64

Answer (score 16):

Inspect is, indeed, included in the Windows 10 "standalone SDK" available from Microsoft [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). Note the installer stub allows you to download several "features" (additional toolkits and utility packages) besides the Windows SDK proper. If all you want is Inspect, you can save yourself downloading about 300MB (650MB installed) of unnecessary packages by deselecting everything except "Windows Software Development Kit":

[image: SDK Feauture Selection Window]

As for an alternative to Inspect, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8299173/4107124) suggests [Windows Detective](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowdetective/). Not having used the tool, I can't speak personally to its safety or suitability for the purpose, so caveat emptor, YMMV, May the Force Be With You and all that.

Comment: This worked for me. FYI, installing this SDK doesn't create any shortcuts, you just have to find the `inspect.exe` in `\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86` or in the 64-bit equivalent location depending on which version you installed.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, you can also install Inspect via the Visual Studio Installer.

All you need is to install the following feature, or a later version:

> Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

After doing that you should find inspect.exe in the following location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\<version>\x64

Comment: This is a great answer for installation, but as noted in the accepted answer, the EXE location is now `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\<some version>\x64`.

Answer (score 11):

In windows 10, Inspect.exe is available at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\arm64`.

Comment: This path will not be available in windows by default if you did not install ADK/SDK kit. Hence you are depended with SDK

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\inspect.exe worked for me

Comment: Didn't realize I had it installed already until I read this answer. Please note that the path may vary based on the **SDK version** *(`10.0.17763.0` is the version)* & **system processor** *(`arm64` or `arm86` or `x64` or `x86`)*

Answer (score 3):

Steps in Jul 2022

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

Download the 22621.1.220506-1250.ni_release_WindowsSDK.iso and launch it, windows 10 will automatically mount it as D.

Install this: d:\Installers\Windows SDK for Windows Store Apps Tools-x86_en-us.msi

After that, inspect.exe will be available in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\inspect.exe

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find the tool in the Windows 10 SDK, you should be able to download and install the Windows 8.1 SDK from the SDK archive page:

> **[Windows and Windows Phone SDK archive](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/sdk-archive)**

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the second part of the question, about an alternative, I've tested an interesting one that works very well, FlaUInspect. Is targeted for an "automation perspective", giving details useful for writing automated tests for example.

Is open source under an MIT license. Can be [found on GitHub](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUInspect).

[image: screen shot of FlaUInspect]

Answer (score 1):

Inspect is available here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64`. Based on version changes you can find it in one of the versions under the `x64` folder.

Answer (score 1):

if you still do not find inspect.exe:

in program files, locate entry , right click on change:
[image: sdk entry]

confirm:

[image]

select SDK for UWP:

[image]

check version number in title bar:

[image: title bar]

ensure to locate correct version directory:

[image]

then you have it:

[image]