# Which tool is compatible with windows 10 for extract windows element for window gui automation

Tags: winappdriver, winium

Which tool is compatible with windows 10 for extract window element for  window gui automation tools like winAppdriver, winium, appium window automation etc

Many are listed in below URL:

https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool

But most of them showing virus or dangerous by system.

I am not able to found any link where from I can download authenticate tool which can extract window element for window 10 specially.

Any reference will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIAVerify is also useful, and doesn't suffer from the strange pauses that block Inspect.

It's also part of the Windows 10 SDK, installed in a folder of the same name. 
The .EXE is called VisualUIAVerifyNative.exe

Comment: Thanks @Robin .. thats a nice tool :) ... accepting your answer and vote up too :)

Answer (score 1):

Download the window development kit from below URL:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Working download URL for now:

[Click Here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/A/0/5A08CEF4-3EC9-494A-9578-AB687E716C12/windowssdk/winsdksetup.exe?ocid=wdgcx1803-download-installer)

Refer below link and refer @raffamaiden answer and download both package

[How to install the Inspect tool on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760513/how-to-install-the-inspect-tool-on-windows-10)

Now open your related system package only, in my case it is x64, wrong pacakge will give error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x64
```

OR

Go the windows kit folder and find inspect.exe or accevent.exe, I personally like inspect more than accevent.exe

Answer (score 0):

UI-Spy also works fine, to extract elements form Windows apps