# c# winapi to sendmessage to a powerbuilder application

Tags: c#, winapi, powerbuilder

in my work we have a legacy application that has the database of all the customer that we are catering for. It was built using PowerBuilder and I am trying to automation data scraping and data input into it's form using win32API however I cannot get the handle window of each textboxes/combo box.

FindWindow and FindWindowEx doesn't find the handle window of those PowerBuilder element.

We are running on Win7 by the way

Comment: First, use [spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) to get the handle of the textboxes/combo box. If it cannot be obtained, `FindWindow` will not work. Then you can try to use the [inspect.exe tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760513/how-to-install-the-inspect-tool-on-windows-10) to get UI elements. If you can get their handles, then [UI Automation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) will be what you need.

Comment: I've tried both spy++ and inspect, they only detect top level elements but the textboxes are deep within the hierarchy and grandchildren of grandchildren, will try ui automation

Comment: OK. You can [Finding Elements in a Subtree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-obtainingelements#finding-elements-in-a-subtree). If you have any progress, please feel free to update in the question.

Comment: PowerBuilder uses own window structures. (At one time, PowerBuilder supported non-Wine Linux) If you have the source code, you can pull out the queries.